# How to apply CSS override based upon text applied to an object?

Tags: css, overriding

I am using a platform I cannot change/configure (Salesforce's Community Cloud), so in order to alter the UI, I need to apply a CSS override.

In the UI, on the question detail page (which shows only the parent post and all associated replies), it:
1) truncates each reply to the first several lines
2) offers "Show More" or "Expand More" clickable text to expand the post

I want to override only when the text applied to the object meets a specific condition, is this possible?

I have used this override and it works but is applied globally to the object

```css
/* Hides the .cuf-more object */
.forceChatterFeedBodyText .cuf-more {display:none !important;}
/* when this .cuf-more object is hidden, I want to override a max-height variable and show all of what is there */
.forceChatterFeedBodyText .feedBodyInnerTruncated {max-height:100% !important;}
```

I don't want it to apply to every instance of the object, only where a sub-specification is the text applied/used:

Use for this condition (where text is "Show More"):

```css
<a tabindex="0" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Show more text" class="cuf-more fadeOut">
<div class="">Show More</div></a>
```

Do NOT use for this one (where text is "Expand Post"):

```css
<a tabindex="0" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Show more text" class="cuf-more fadeOut">
<div class="">Expand Post</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a specific class name identifier in each case.

For example:

```
<div class="show-more">Show More</div>
<div class="expand-post">Expand Post</div>
```

Then you can query for the class names in the CSS with

```
.show-more {

}

.expand-post {

}
```

Comment: Thanks @emmawedekind - I am not clear on your answer and how I would apply this as an override? As mentioned I cannot create a class, this is with a platform I cannot touch, so I can only affect it with overrides.